# PS3 cannot find Tversity Media Server after new router install

Tags: router, connection, ps3, media-server

I just replaced my Belkin Router with a new Belkin router (N150). After configuration, I have my PS3 and my PC both showing up as DHCP clients. Both can reach the internet as well.

I can ping the PS3 and router from my PC. However, my PS cannot set my tversity media server. All three are using wired connections.

Any idea what could be happening. Am I missing something?

Thanks!!

Comment: I'm going to guess it's a Universal Plug & Play issue. Check if your router has UPNP set up on it.

Comment: I have tried with router's UPNP enabled and disabled, no difference. My old router had UPNP disabled. I think there is UPNP going on betreen the media server and PS3 though. I don't believe it needs router UPNP support, as trafic is not leaving the subnet.